# Is it possible to execute many stored procedures in a single operation?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am coding to read xml files to update the database. I get about 500 xml files and I want to process them as fast I can.

All database operations are done using stored procedures.

There are about 35 different stored procedures called for each xml file.

Initially I had written the code like this

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC UpdateTeamStats("+teamId+","+points+")");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

but after going through some best practices I changed it to

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateTeamStats");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("teamId", 21);
cmd.Parameters.Add("points", 2);
```

because of the high number of stored procedures being called from the program I realized I have to make lesser number of calls in order to optimize.

So I want to collect all the 35 stored procedures together and execute them in one go.

The stored procedures are different with different parameters and I dont know a way to collect and execute them together after the parameter changes I did above.

I was thinking of calling one giant stored procedure and inside that stored procedure calling the other 35 , but I am not very good at SQL and it will lead to unnecessary complexity.

Is it Possible to do this entirely in C#?

Or is there some other better method to queue up the storedprocedures and run them quickly

Comment: What do you expect to happen when in the middle of your execution, an error has occurred? Will all the executed procedures rollback? Or just continue processing the remaining procedures?

Comment: Note that your title says "in parallel" but reading your question, it looks like you just mean "as one database command"

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - That was my edit. The original was "in one go".

Comment: John , when a single error occurs I want to perform a rollback

Comment: George , yes I meant that in one operation

Comment: Do u mean sp in one transaction ???

Comment: Ankit , yes in one transaction\operation

Answer (score 1):

Please download Microsoft Applications Data block from

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=435

Fine, But how do I use it?

Usage of this wrapper class is quite simple.

```
DAC DC = new DAC();
DC.StoredProcedure = "nProc_InsertOrder";
DC.Params.Add("@OrderId", SqlDbType.VarChar, "Order1" );
DC.Params.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.VarChar, "test");
DAC.Commands.Add(DC);

DC = new DAC();
DC.StoredProcedure = "nProc_InsertOrderLineItems";
DC.Params.Add("@OrderId", SqlDbType.VarChar, "Order1" );
DC.Params.Add("@OrderLineId", SqlDbType.VarChar, "A1");
DAC.Commands.Add(DC);

DC = new DAC();
DC.StoredProcedure = "nProc_InsertOrderLineItems";
DC.Params.Add("@OrderId", SqlDbType.VarChar, "Order1" );
DC.Params.Add("@OrderLineId", SqlDbType.VarChar, "A2");
DAC.Commands.Add(DC);

DC = new DAC();
DC.StoredProcedure = "nProc_CreateBill";
DC.Params.Add("@BillDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, DateTime.Now);
DC.Params.Add("@BillId", SqlDbType.VarChar, "Bill1");
DAC.Commands.Add(DC);
DAC.ExecuteBatch();
```

If the order insertion is failed, the bill should not be created. Similarly, if the line items are failed, then the order should not be created. We are achieving this in just a few lines of code through ADO.Net.

In this example, till we call ExecuteBatch, we are not actually inserting the records but preparing the object for making batch updations.

Comment: Where does the main DAC object come from - the one we're using for `DAC.Commands.Add`? It can't be static else this wouldn't be thread-safe! And does this really do what we want here - without explicit support from the SQL Server client classes does this really just do a single DB round-trip or instead wrap all the commands in a transaction?

Comment: We are wrapping all commands in a single object and executing them in a single open connection with transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution imo would be to write a single stored procedure with a table-valued parameter passed in that contains a list of all the parameters per xml file. Then in this stored proc call all the other stored procs for each record in the table-valued parameter.

If this is not ok, then you could use a SqlCommand of type text instead of stored procedure and just build the command as you go and execute it. You can use parameters as you do now or you can just write dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `CommandQueue`, via the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and create a delegate on the command that maps to whatever your requirements are for the call to the stored procedure; by the looks, something like:

```
public class CommandQueue
{
    private Connection _connexion = new Connection(); // Set this up somehow.

    // Other methods to handle the concurrency/ calling/ transaction etc.

    public Func<string, Dictionary<string, int>, bool> CallStoredProcedure = (procedureName, parameterValueMap) =>
    {
      cmd.Connection = GetConnexion();
      var cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      foreach (var parameterValueMapping in parameterValueMap)
      {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterValueMapping.Key, parameterValueMapping.Value);
      }

      var success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      return success;
    }

    private Connection GetConnexion()
    {
      return _connexion;
    }
}
```

And then, setup the `CommandQueue`, so that you have a pool of threads, from which you can call the delegate on a new thread, so that they run in parallel.

Actually, looking at the [SQLCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4956bkc.aspx) class, you can make asynchronous calls on it.  So, you should be able to call each of your stored procedures asynchronously, setup a delegate for when each completes and wrap it all in a transaction, so that you can roll them back when you need by calling `Cancel()` on each command.  I'd probably still use a `CommandQueue` in order to abstract this out, as I'd suggest you'll probably change it later!

I think I'd still encapsulate the stored procedure-calling with a delegate on a `CommandQueue`, so that this abstracts out the details of the stored proc and makes the process easier to understand for anyone else and also easier to maintain.  It'll be much easier if you add new stored procs, or change the name, or something.  You can setup a static list can contains all the delegates, or a static list with the necessary stored procedure details and use the delegate to pass-in just the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, and in my experience using ADO.NET, I think you will have no issue whatsoever executing these as **separate** statements using a **single** `SqlConnection`.

This has the benefit of leveraging .NET's amazing [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling), enables you to work/customize/interact with each command individually and rides a shared connection (reducing the amount of connection brokering to a trivial amount).

I'd also like to emphasize the important of the `using` clauses here that facilitate the proper disposal of the various resources.

For example:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //ready to query 
        conn.Open();

        cmd.CommandText = "UpdateTeamStats";
        var teamIdParam = new SqlParameter("teamId", 21);
        var pointsParam = new SqlParameter("points", 2);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(teamIdParam);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pointsParam);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //OR if you're async cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

        //the rest of your executions

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

And if I'm being solicitous for a moment, you can use a library, like mine [DbConnect](https://github.com/pimbrouwers/DbConnect), which reduces the above to:

```
using (var db = new DbConnect("connection string"))
{
    db.SetSqlCommand("UpdateTeamStats");
    db.AddParameter("teamId", 21);
    db.AddParameter("points", 2);

    db.ExecuteNonQuery().Wait(); //OR if youre async await db.ExecuteNonQuery();

    db.ClearParameters();
    db.SetSqlCommand("some other proc");

    //rest of executions
}
```